# Implementation of remote()

Tags: android, linux, ipc, rpc, android-source

I'm trying to find the implementation of remote(), as in:

```
remote()->transact(CODE, data, &reply);
```

Do you guys know where it is? Searching Google turned out futile.
Or if you know what that function does, it would be a big help for me.
Many thanks

Update: it seems remote() will return a pointer to an object of type BBinder, IBinder, BpBinder, or IPCThreadState but I'm not sure which one.

Comment: remote() typically returns a BpBinder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of `remote` is simple:

```
class BpRefBase : public virtual RefBase
{
protected:
                            BpRefBase(const sp<IBinder>& o);
    virtual                 ~BpRefBase();
    virtual void            onFirstRef();
    virtual void            onLastStrongRef(const void* id);
    virtual bool            onIncStrongAttempted(uint32_t flags, const void* id);

    inline  IBinder*        remote()                { return mRemote; }
    inline  IBinder*        remote() const          { return mRemote; }

private:
                            BpRefBase(const BpRefBase& o);
    BpRefBase&              operator=(const BpRefBase& o);

    IBinder* const          mRemote;
    RefBase::weakref_type*  mRefs;
    volatile int32_t        mState;
};
```

The `ServiceManager` will manage all the registered service, for how it works, check [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15513172/1365960). When you `getService` from `ServiceManager`, it will return an `IBinder` object represents that service, then this `IBinder` object will be put into a `BpInterface`. That is your remote. Then you can use that `BpInterface` to start binder transaction with the actual `service(BnInterface)`.

```
template<typename INTERFACE>
class BpInterface : public INTERFACE, public BpRefBase
{
public:
                                BpInterface(const sp<IBinder>& remote);

protected:
    virtual IBinder*            onAsBinder();
};
```

All familiar `BpXXX` like `BpCamera`, `BpCameraService` extends from `BpInterface`.