# Where to find the implementation of the Android Camera API locking mechanism?

Tags: android, android-camera

The camera API use the open() and release() calls to prevent multiple accesses from different apps/processes, but I kind of want to know how the underlying mechanism works. For example, is there a mutex share across different processes? Can anyone point me to the right place, I did some Google search but I can't locate the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I linked some kitkat source, since it's the last version before `android.hardware.camera2` was introduced.

The lock is tried like this:

```cpp
remote()->transact(LOCK, data, &reply);
```

where `remote()` seems to be a system service. Refer to this answer about remote: [Implementation of remote()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520098/implementation-of-remote)

### Android source code

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/core/java/android/hardware/Camera.java:

```java
public native final void lock();
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/core/jni/android_hardware_Camera.cpp:

```cpp
static void android_hardware_Camera_lock(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)
{
    ALOGV("lock");
    sp<Camera> camera = get_native_camera(env, thiz, NULL);
    if (camera == 0) return;
    if (camera->lock() != NO_ERROR) {
        jniThrowRuntimeException(env, "lock failed");
    }
}
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/camera/Camera.cpp:

```cpp
status_t Camera::lock()
{
    sp <ICamera> c = mCamera;
    if (c == 0) return NO_INIT;
    return c->lock();
}
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/include/camera/ICamera.h:

```cpp
class ICamera: public IInterface
{
    // prevent other processes from using this ICamera interface
    virtual status_t        lock() = 0;
}
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/camera/ICamera.cpp:

```cpp
class BpCamera: public BpInterface<ICamera>
{
    virtual status_t lock()
    {
        Parcel data, reply;
        data.writeInterfaceToken(ICamera::getInterfaceDescriptor());
        remote()->transact(LOCK, data, &reply);
        return reply.readInt32();
    }
}
```